# R Shiny renderText with paste variable ignoring sep = "\t"

Tags: html, r, shiny, separator

Suppose I have the following shiny app. I am trying to get var1:3 to space out nicely but it is ignoring my inputs. I have tried sep =  "    ", and sep = "\t".

Any ideas why this is not working?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

            htmlOutput("test")
)

server <- function(input,output) {
  output$test <- renderText({

    var1<- "one"
    var2 <- "two" 
    var3 <- "three"

   output<-  paste(var1,var2,var3,sep = "       ")})}




   shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)



  Desired output:

  one            two          three
```

Comment: It may be that you are not escaping the backslash. Did you try `sep = "\\t"`?

Comment: @C.Braun tried, doesn't fix the issue